# C# How to write page number when split large pdf file into small multiple pdf file

Tags: c#, pdf, itext

I have many large pdf files which have many pages. I have to split those large pdf into small multiple pdf files.

I have a code which I can use to split large pdf into small multiple pdf files.
Below code, I am using for splitting.

```
private void SplitAndSaveInterval(string pdfFilePath, string outputPath, int startPage, int interval, string pdfFileName)  
{
    using (PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(pdfFilePath))  
    {  
        Document document = new Document();  
        PdfCopy copy = new PdfCopy(document, new FileStream(outputPath + "\\" + pdfFileName + ".pdf", FileMode.Create));  
        document.Open();  

        for (int pagenumber = startPage; pagenumber < (startPage + interval); pagenumber++)  
        {  
            if (reader.NumberOfPages >= pagenumber)  
            {  
                copy.AddPage(copy.GetImportedPage(reader, pagenumber));  
            }  
            else  
            {  
                break;  
            }  
        }  

        document.Close();  
    }  
}
```

This code is taken from https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/splitting-pdf-file-in-c-sharp-using-itextsharp/

I got a routine which adds the page number. Routine attached:

```
void AddPageNumber(string fileIn, string fileOut)
{
    byte[] bytes = File.ReadAllBytes(fileIn);
    Font blackFont = FontFactory.GetFont("Arial", 12, Font.NORMAL, BaseColor.BLACK);
    using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(bytes);
        using (PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, stream))
        {
            int pages = reader.NumberOfPages;
            for (int i = 1; i <= pages; i++)
            {
                ColumnText.ShowTextAligned(stamper.GetUnderContent(i), Element.ALIGN_RIGHT, new Phrase(i.ToString(), blackFont), 568f, 15f, 0);
            }
        }
        bytes = stream.ToArray();
    }
    File.WriteAllBytes(fileOut, bytes);
}
```

Now my question is how to incorporate or call AddPageNumber() routine from SplitAndSaveInterval() routine to finally add page number on each page at the top right portion of the newly generated pdf file.

Looking for help and suggestion. thanks

Comment: You are using an old version of iText that is no longer supported. If you upgrade to [iText 7](https://developers.itextpdf.com/itext7/download-and-install-information/NET), you'll notice that what you are trying to achieve is much easier with iText 7 when compared to iText 5.

Comment: http://what-when-how.com/itext-5/copying-pages-with-pdfcopy-itext-5/

Comment: The page you are referring to is an illegal copy of the book I wrote in 2009. That's 9 years ago. Please upgrade to iText 7 or explain why that's not an option for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your using iTextSharp, have you tried the following from their documentation:

```
public void onEndPage(PdfWriter writer, Document document) {
Rectangle rect = writer.getBoxSize("art");
switch(writer.getPageNumber() % 2) {
case 0:
    ColumnText.showTextAligned(writer.getDirectContent(),
        Element.ALIGN_RIGHT, header[0],
        rect.getRight(), rect.getTop(), 0);
    break;
case 1:
    ColumnText.showTextAligned(writer.getDirectContent(),
        Element.ALIGN_LEFT, header[1],
        rect.getLeft(), rect.getTop(), 0);
    break;
}
ColumnText.showTextAligned(writer.getDirectContent(),
    Element.ALIGN_CENTER, new Phrase(String.format("page %d", pagenumber)),
    (rect.getLeft() + rect.getRight()) / 2, rect.getBottom() - 18, 0);
}
```

https://developers.itextpdf.com/question/how-add-text-left-and-right-header

Comment: The op uses itext's `PdfCopy` class to create pdfs from existing pdfs. Page events are for use with a plain `PdfWriter` creating pdfs from scratch.

Comment: i am using itextsharp library. now tell me how could i attach onEndPage event when working with PdfCopy class ? when pdf copy will add each page then i need to add page no on each page....how it is possible ?

Comment: As @mkl explains, you can't combine page events in combination with `PdfCopy`. Please upgrade to iText 7 or explain why that is not an option for you.

Comment: @BrunoLowagie itextsharp used in big project. if i upgrade then i may need to test lots of code to make sure all are working. i depend on my manager. he may not allow to upgrade. may i can use itext7 in new project not in existing one.

Comment: Please ask your manager if the project complies with the AGPL license. If it does, please share more info with iText Software.